# Не работает данный код в бат скрипт

Tags: bat

```
set /p funct=
if %funct%=="adb-sideload-{Firmvare1.0-class=folder}" (goto:1) else (goto:2)
```

я ввожу **adb-sideload-{Firmvare1.0-class=folder}**, но ничего не происходит. ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: А что должно происходить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В коде все есть. Когда funct = adb-sideload-{Firmvare1.0-class=folder} то батник выполнит блок  1, а если  что то другое, то выполнит блок 2.

Comment: В коде нет ни блока 1 ни блока 2

Comment: под названием "блок" я имею ввиду то, на что переходит скрипт после команды Goto.

Comment: В представленном коде нет ничего, куда можно было бы перейти. Данный код бессмысленнен, т.к. отсутсвуют метки, на которые и должен переходить goto

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка в операторе сравнения

```
if %funct%=="adb-sideload-{Firmvare1.0-class=folder}" (goto:1) else (goto:2)
```

У вас слева нет кавычек, справа есть, поэтому строки не равны, и всегда выполняется блок 2.
Нужно указывать кавычки явно:

```
if "%funct%"=="adb-sideload-{Firmvare1.0-class=folder}" (goto:1) else (goto:2)
```